# How do I import public keys when using KGPG?

Tags: gpg

I installed GnuPG and KGPG. I created a text doc whereby I wrote down nothing except the other person's public key configuration. There is a tab for importing public keys. However, when I select the file for import, it does not import it. When trying it manually, without KGPG, I get the error message: no valid KGPG data.

Probably the same thing with exporting data.

Am I supposed to be adding their public key to a "file" in a different way? I name the file xyz.key and I get a special looking icon.

**UPDATE**:
I seem to have figured it out, at least in-part. The main thing was first using the "export public key" tab and saving it using the clipboard (not file) and then transferring via copy/paste to a doc. This saved the public keys in an encrypted form. Then when the person receives this, they use the import tab and the encrypted data of the public key gets imported correctly. The "no valid KGPG data" message I was getting before was because I was trying to import & export non-encrypted key data. The fact that I am unable to fully get the entire gpg encryption thing to work makes me wonder if I did it correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: if you believe you have a good question and a good answer, I recommend you consider adding your answer as an answer, rather than editing your question. That way, others can show they agree with your answer. Alternatively, simply remove your entire post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thing was first using the "export public key" tab and saving it using the clipboard (not file) and then transferring via copy/paste to a doc. This saved the public keys in an encrypted form. Then when the person receives this, they use the import tab and the encrypted data of the public key gets imported correctly. The "no valid KGPG data" message I was getting before was because I was trying to import & export non-encrypted key data. The fact that I am unable to fully get the entire gpg encryption thing to work makes me wonder if I did it correctly.